# SqlDataReader has no Connection property

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using .NET Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012 and read its help on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.connection.aspx. But in my code I cant get access to this property - it is inaccessible to a copy of SqlDataReader. How can I get readers SqlConnection ?

Comment: Can you share your code?? As it would help to understnd your problem better!!!

Comment: Why do you need to access it?  The `SqlCommand` you have used to get the `SqlDataReader` has a _public_ property [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx).

Comment: I need it because I dont want pass two arguments to the method instead of one.

Comment: Why do you pass a `SqlDataReader` to another method at all? You should consume it where you executed it.

Comment: To reduce number of cycles in one method. I give him to other method and there already in a cycle I read out fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access it because this property is protected:

> protected SqlConnection Connection { get; }